# In which Category Inverse Limit does not exist?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

We know that in category of $\mathbb{Set}$ the inverse limit is the direct product. But I am looking for specific category in which inverse limit does not exist. Any comments would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that every partial order can be viewed as a category (with a unique morphism $A\rightarrow B$ whenever $A\le B$. Consider $(\mathbb{N}, <)$ as a category $\mathcal{N}$, and think about $\mathcal{N}^{op}$; the whole category forms an inverse system, but it has no inverse limit since there is no largest natural number.

*(If you don't require inverse systems to be directed, things are simpler: consider the two-object category with no non-identity morphisms.)*

Comment: Thank you, that is true, but another question: In the category of fields inverse limit does not exist?

Comment: @B.K-Theory It depends if you allow non-directed inverse systems. If so, the answer is no (consider two fields of different characteristic).

Comment: Actually the morphisms must be isomorphisms or injectives, so we cannot find the inverse limit?

Answer (score 2):

Try the category of *finite* sets and the following inverse system:

- $ I=-\Bbb N$
- $A_{n}= \{0,1,\ldots,-n\}$ for $n\in-\Bbb N$
- $f_{i,j}\colon A_i\to A_j$ given by $f_{i,j}(x)=\begin{cases}x,&x\in A_j\\0,&x\notin A_j\end{cases}$ for $i,j\in-\Bbb N$, $i\le j$

Then ${\lim\limits_{\leftarrow}}_{i\in I}A_i$ does not exist because it would have to be infinite.